# How can I crop and export parts of STL Objects?

Tags: objects, export

I'm a blender beginner. I have an .STL of an anatomical figure and I need to crop a small chunk of it and export it in a separat .STL file, but so far I haven't found anything quite relevant on the web. Since I'm a blender-nobb, I figured out I don't even know what to search for exactly.

Comment: What do you mean by "crop"? I'm only familiar with that term in a 2D setting and I see a couple different ways it could apply here.

Comment: I have a maxilary 3D scan and I need to select a tooth and export it in a different STL in order to create a few different final STLs with that tooth in different positions from the original one (either rotated or moved a few mm right or left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking into the Boolean modifier?

If you object is a **closed, watertight, manifold mesh** you could use Boolean operations to break it into chunks of the desirable parts.

Just create a new closed watertight mesh object that as a shape or volume that engulfs or includes the part of the STL you want to keep and use it in a Boolean operation to intersect with the existing mesh and extract the part you want.

You can also try the *Knife Project* operator if a simpler cutting or slicing of the original geometry in one direction will suffice to obtain what you want.
You can use something as simple as a plane or a bezier curve to cut your geometry in the desired way.

[image: Curve knife project]

**Edit** If your object is already composed of separate parts but all joined in a single object you can simply enter edit mode, select them all press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate them and select the option *All loose parts* to divide them into different objects.