# Is the File too Big or is Blender too Slow?

Tags: modeling, performance

I am just now getting involved in photogrammetry and as we know the files are quite large. I am importing an .OBJ file from Meshroom and from the import to any other click there is lag.

Being new I am trying everything to speed it up, I thought deleting large parts of the file would help, but there is no clear way that I can delete from my import. I would like to speed this process up.

TWO QUESTIONS:

1. Please what is the easiest way to delete a large amount of data from the image? (E.g. a counter top around a coffee cup. Or maybe grass around a concrete pad that has a statue on it. Or part of a cloud that was mistakenly brought into the photogrammetry process?)
2. SPEED... baby SPEED. I am using the box select tool (<kbd>B</kbd>) to choose an area then <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the vertices, I rotate around to make sure to get as much as I can but with the lag there is 5-10 sec wait between clicks.

   I saw a video once where someone used a plane to remove everything under it or to the left of it. I thought that might work best but I cannot seem to find that video again.

Comment: *"used a plane to remove everything under it"* See Knife Project https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66942/how-would-you-model-a-sphere-with-a-shell-like-object/

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51280/how-can-i-crop-and-export-parts-of-stl-objects/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/slice-up-terrain-mesh-into-chunks

Comment: You can also select the *Linked Objects* by placing your *cursor* on the object and press L on your keyboard